# How can i remove/hide window close button not dialog box in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, popupwindow

I am opening a url in window and all i want is to remove or hide the close button of window.
here is my code.
`window.open('/open-window', Test Window, "height=600,width=600,titlebar=no,location=no,close=no");`

[image]

I want to remove the window close button as user has to use the provided X button. thanks in advance

Comment: I would close your window with Task Manager, and never visit at your page again, if you'd remove the close button from _my browser_.

Comment: the issue is i have to remove the id of the user who is on this window from an array. can you please guide to a better way to do this.

Comment: Maybe [send a beacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)?

Comment: is it a replacement of window??

Comment: Nope, it's a way to send some information to your server after a window was closed. Maybe you should ask a new question about your real problem ..?

Comment: could you please provide an example how can I do this? please...

Comment: Like said above, please ask a new question about the problem you're trying to solve by hiding the close button. This is not a correct place to answer that.

Comment: can you please provide ans here as i am not able to post new question for 90 min.